# Playwright - How to access TestInfo outside of test function?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, playwright

In Playwright, is there any way to access current TestInfo outside of a test function?

I have some tests that need access to the current testInfo.snapshotDir. However, the 'e_compareImages' function that needs the testInfo is nested several layers deep. It is not practical to pass the testInfo from the test function all the way to the function that needs that info.

I know e_compareImages() already has *some* access to the current testInfo because the function calls toMatchSnapshot() (from Jest's expect library), and the function pulls the correct file from the current testInfo.snapshotDir

Is there any way for functions in the actionHelper file to access current testInfo outside of an expect assertion?

I've posted what I believe are the relevant portions of the files below.

// LoginPage.test.js File

```
const { test } = require('@playwright/test');

test("Verify logo on Login page", async () => {
    await loginPage.verifyLogo();
});
```

// actionHelper.js File

```
const { expect } = require('@playwright/test');

async e_compareImages(selector, expectedImageFileName) {
    let locator= await this.page.locator(selector);
    const actualImage = await locator.screenshot({scale: 'device'});
    await expect(actualImage).toMatchSnapshot(expectedImageFileName);
}
```

I've tried importing Playwright's globals.js library and using its currentTestInfo(), but I have been unable to get it to work.

Is there another library or a way to extend an existing library that would do what I need?

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. You can use the below code to require the globals library

```
var _globals = require("../node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/globals");
```

Then you can use this function to get the current testInfo object directly (without having to pass the object through however many intermediary functions)

```
// Get the current test's testInfo object
async getCurrentTestInfo() {
    const curTestInfo = await (0, _globals.currentTestInfo)();
    return await curTestInfo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access **TestInfo** object outside of a test function using the **test** method's second argument:

```
async e_compareImages(testInfo, selector, expectedImageFileName) {
  // ...
  const actualImage = await locator.screenshot({scale: 'device'});
  await expect(actualImage).toMatchSnapshot(testInfo, expectedImageFileName);
}
```

Now, when you call **e_compareImage** function you can pass the **TestInfo** object as an argument:

```
test("Verify logo on Login page", async (testInfo) => {
  await loginPage.verifyLogo(testInfo);
});
```